# pppd Works in windows, but not in routers?

Tags: linux, window, pptp, pppd, smc

I have a pppd server runing in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it's configured for chap authetifications. And when i try to connect to my server only works on windows (10 or versions bellow) but i would like to put the pptp directly on the router (I already have done this in the past with NordVPN before December 1st) but the router (Dlink DIR-809) don't connect to my server and the logs don't show anything.

This is how i have configured my pptp-options

```
###############################################################################
#
#
# Sample Poptop PPP options file /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
# Options used by PPP when a connection arrives from a client.
# This file is pointed to by /etc/pptpd.conf option keyword.
# Changes are effective on the next connection.  See "man pppd".
#
# You are expected to change this file to suit your system.  As
# packaged, it requires PPP 2.4.2 and the kernel MPPE module.
###############################################################################


# Authentication

# Name of the local system for authentication purposes
# (must match the second field in /etc/ppp/chap-secrets entries)

# Optional: domain name to use for authentication
# domain domain.com

# Strip the domain prefix from the username before authentication.
# (applies if you use pppd with chapms-strip-domain patch)
#chapms-strip-domain


# Encryption
# (There have been multiple versions of PPP with encryption support,
# choose with of the following sections you will use.)


# BSD licensed ppp-2.4.2 upstream with MPPE only, kernel module ppp_mppe.o
# {{{

# Require the peer to authenticate itself using MS-CHAPv2 [Microsoft
# Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol, Version 2] authentication.
# Require MPPE 128-bit encryption
# (note that MPPE requires the use of MSCHAP-V2 during authentication)
# }}}




# Network and Routing

# If pppd is acting as a server for Microsoft Windows clients, this
# option allows pppd to supply one or two DNS (Domain Name Server)
# addresses to the clients.  The first instance of this option
# specifies the primary DNS address; the second instance (if given)
# specifies the secondary DNS address.
# Attention! This information may not be taken into account by a Windows
# client. See KB311218 in Microsoft's knowledge base for more information.
ms-dns 192.168.1.1
ms-dns 192.168.0.1

# If pppd is acting as a server for Microsoft Windows or "Samba"
# clients, this option allows pppd to supply one or two WINS (Windows
# Internet Name Services) server addresses to the clients.  The first
# instance of this option specifies the primary WINS address; the
# second instance (if given) specifies the secondary WINS address.
#ms-wins 10.0.0.3
#ms-wins 10.0.0.4

# Add an entry to this system's ARP [Address Resolution Protocol]
# table with the IP address of the peer and the Ethernet address of this
# system.  This will have the effect of making the peer appear to other
# systems to be on the local ethernet.
# (you do not need this if your PPTP server is responsible for routing
# packets to the clients -- James Cameron)
proxyarp

# Normally pptpd passes the IP address to pppd, but if pptpd has been
# given the delegate option in pptpd.conf or the --delegate command line
# option, then pppd will use chap-secrets or radius to allocate the
# client IP address.  The default local IP address used at the server
# end is often the same as the address of the server.  To override this,
# specify the local IP address here.
# (you must not use this unless you have used the delegate option)
#10.8.0.100

# Debian: do not replace the default route
nodefaultroute


# Logging

# Enable connection debugging facilities.
# (see your syslog configuration for where pppd sends to)
#debug

# Print out all the option values which have been set.
# (often requested by mailing list to verify options)
#dump


# Miscellaneous

# Create a UUCP-style lock file for the pseudo-tty to ensure exclusive
# access.
lock

# Disable BSD-Compress compression
nobsdcomp

# Disable Van Jacobson compression
# (needed on some networks with Windows 9x/ME/XP clients, see posting to
# poptop-server on 14th April 2005 by Pawel Pokrywka and followups,
# http://marc.theaimsgroup.com/?t=111343175400006&r=1&w=2 )
novj
novjccomp

# turn off logging to stderr, since this may be redirected to pptpd,
# which may trigger a loopback
nologfd

# put plugins here
# (putting them higher up may cause them to sent messages to the pty)
name pptpd
require-chap
login
auth
```

And my pptpd.conf

```
###############################################################################
# $Id$
#
# Sample Poptop configuration file /etc/pptpd.conf
#
# Changes are effective when pptpd is restarted.
###############################################################################

# TAG: ppp
#   Path to the pppd program, default '/usr/sbin/pppd' on Linux
#
#ppp /usr/sbin/pppd

# TAG: option
#   Specifies the location of the PPP options file.
#   By default PPP looks in '/etc/ppp/options'
#
option  /etc/ppp/pptpd-options

# TAG: debug
#   Turns on (more) debugging to syslog
#
#debug

# TAG: stimeout
#   Specifies timeout (in seconds) on starting ctrl connection
#
# stimeout 10

# TAG: noipparam
#       Suppress the passing of the client's IP address to PPP, which is
#       done by default otherwise.
#
#noipparam

# TAG: logwtmp
#   Use wtmp(5) to record client connections and disconnections.
#
logwtmp

# TAG: bcrelay <if>
#   Turns on broadcast relay to clients from interface <if>
#
#bcrelay eth1

# TAG: delegate
#   Delegates the allocation of client IP addresses to pppd.
#
#       Without this option, which is the default, pptpd manages the list of
#       IP addresses for clients and passes the next free address to pppd.
#       With this option, pptpd does not pass an address, and so pppd may use
#       radius or chap-secrets to allocate an address.
#
#delegate

# TAG: connections
#       Limits the number of client connections that may be accepted.
#
#       If pptpd is allocating IP addresses (e.g. delegate is not
#       used) then the number of connections is also limited by the
#       remoteip option.  The default is 100.
#connections 100

# TAG: localip
# TAG: remoteip
#   Specifies the local and remote IP address ranges.
#
#   These options are ignored if delegate option is set.
#
#       Any addresses work as long as the local machine takes care of the
#       routing.  But if you want to use MS-Windows networking, you should
#       use IP addresses out of the LAN address space and use the proxyarp
#       option in the pppd options file, or run bcrelay.
#
#   You can specify single IP addresses seperated by commas or you can
#   specify ranges, or both. For example:
#
#       192.168.0.234,192.168.0.245-249,192.168.0.254
#
#   IMPORTANT RESTRICTIONS:
#
#   1. No spaces are permitted between commas or within addresses.
#
#   2. If you give more IP addresses than the value of connections,
#      it will start at the beginning of the list and go until it
#      gets connections IPs.  Others will be ignored.
#
#   3. No shortcuts in ranges! ie. 234-8 does not mean 234 to 238,
#      you must type 234-238 if you mean this.
#
#   4. If you give a single localIP, that's ok - all local IPs will
#      be set to the given one. You MUST still give at least one remote
#      IP for each simultaneous client.
#
# (Recommended)
localip 192.168.0.1
remoteip    192.168.0.238-245,192.168.0.248
# or
#localip 192.168.0.234-238,192.168.0.245
#remoteip 192.168.1.234-238,192.168.1.245
```

I also have tried in a old SMC router but he said than doesn't support MPPE when it's disabled and, after he give a error like

```
CPP: timeout sending config-request
```

If i enable it the SMC router gives me that

```
LCP terminated by peer (MPPE required but peer refused)
```

So when i tried to files on router loocks like than the router don't support MPPE so i buy now a D-Link DIR-809

But in logs he don't show nothing.

I googled about the SMC Router issue and i found it on this link [pptp client source forge wiki](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#mppe)

And it's say clearly that,

```
    Check MPPE Support
MPPE support is required if you wish to connect to a PPTP Server such as Microsoft Windows VPN Server. MPPE is built as a Linux kernel module, as part of PPP 2.4.2 or later, and as a patch to the PPP 2.4.0.
Both of the following tests must pass for MPPE support to function.
```

I disabled MPPE but i get the issue above (CPP:  Time out receiving config-request )

So i buy a Dlink DIR-809 but no logs(On router) and don't connect, but on Windows works well.

Any Suggestions.

Rgds,

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to start `pppd` manually with the correct options, but include `debug` (or toggle it with SIGUSR1), and have a look at the differences between Windows connecting and the router connecting. The protocol is sufficiently complex that little details can throw it off. Another option is to run `wireshark` etc. to see details about what is happening.

Comment: I try it today, so when is done i told you if i found something. 

Thank You to take care about my issue